# Дайте грамотный совет. Занимаюсь разработкой своего ORM

Tags: jdbc, java, orm

Всем привет. 
Занимаюсь по-тихоньку развитием своей библиотеки объектно-реляционного отображения для Java на основе JDBC. Сразу говорю: я не профессиональный программист, я всего лишь студент 4 курса, но интерес к данной теме есть и хочется сделать что-то стоящее (разбираюсь в новых темах по мере необходимости). Есть желание сделать библиотеку такой, чтобы она была интересна не только мне.

В данный момент уже реализовано:

1. Представление записей в виде объектов сущностных классов, один объект = одна запись. Один сущн. класс = одна таблица;
2. Транзакции;
3. Автоматическая обработка исключений внутри класса EntityClass (обработка вынесена в отдельный скрытый метод, там происходит вызов rollback() или метода для переподключения, в зависимости от ситуации, а так же прочие действия);
4. Автоматическое переподключение в случае потери соединения (выполняется только если не используется транзакция);
5. Подгрузка настроек из properties-файла;
6. Подгрузка подготовленных запросов из файла (будет ещё дорабатываться, хочу что-то вроде хранимых процедур, но на стороне клиента, желательно даже с параметрами);
7. Набор методов в классе Functions для автоматической выборки и прочих вещей (будет ещё дорабатываться);
8. Что-то вроде кеширования, но я не знаю, кеширование ли это. Помимо того, что можно значения полей получать напрямую из ResultSet'а, есть возможность вызвать метод initialization() и тогда содержимое ResultSet'а перегонится в Map, хранимый в объекте EntityClass. После этого нужно вызывать отдельный метод для получения значений из Map'а, отображение не зависят от состояния подключения к БД.
9. Несколько методов для связывания объектов. Например, метод `insertObject(fieldName : String, object : EntityClass) : void` вставляет в указанное поле объект сущн. класса (а на самом деле просто записывает в это поле внешний ключ). Ещё метод `returnObject(fieldName : String, tableName : String) : EntityClass` извлекает из указанного поля объект сущн. класса, принадлежащий указанной таблице. Методы для прочих связей в РБД пока не реализованы.

В принципе, это всё, что пока есть. Хочу обратить внимание на то, что в данный момент есть два способа работы с сущн. классами: создание экземпляра класса EntityClass с передачей ему в качестве параметра имени таблицы, с которой он связан и наследование от EntityClass. При наследовании нужно класс-предок оформлять по строгому шаблону. Такому:

```
package entity;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import db_and_orm.EntityClass;
import db_and_orm.Functions;
import db_and_orm.Transaction;

public class Кафедра extends EntityClass {

    private final static String TABLE_NAME = "кафедры";

    //конструкторы для добавления новой записи 
    //после их вызова нужно вызывать "сеттеры", а затем insertRow)
    //полная выборка
    public Кафедра(Transaction trans) {
        super(trans, TABLE_NAME);
    }

    //частичная выборка
    public Кафедра(Transaction trans, String... поля) {
        super(trans, TABLE_NAME, поля);
    }

    //конструкторы для извлечения готовых записей
    //полная выборка
    public Кафедра(Transaction trans, int id) {
        super(trans, TABLE_NAME, id);
    }

    //частичная выборка
    public Кафедра(Transaction trans, int id, String... поля) {
        super(trans, TABLE_NAME, id, поля);
    }
```

Как видно, поля там не определены, потому что они определяются сами с помощью метаданных (доступ к полям у меня осуществляется исключительно по имени, передаваемому методу get().  То есть POJO классы не используются. Сейчас думаю, а может всё таки попытаться адаптировать всё на POJO классы? Но тогда вопрос, если я буду наследоваться от EntityClass, то откуда базовый класс будет знать, какие конкретно поля я определил в дочернем? Делать абстрактный метод я не хочу, это не дело.

Хочу позже ещё реализовать следующие вещи:

1. Хранимые процедуры и функции;
2. Логирование. Вот тут вопрос: что конкретно нужно логировать в плане работы с БД? Может, дадите ссылку, где описывается, как происходит логирование по-нормальному?
3. Допиливание связей;
4. Применение аннотаций для упрощения работы с библиотекой;
5. Автоматическое составление структуры БД и отправка запросов на создание таблиц по составленной объектной модели на уровне ЯП. Хочу без использования всяких XML, чтобы составление схемы БД происходило только по сущн. классам;
6. Поддержка составных ключей;
7. Какой-нибудь контейнер, где будут выполняться операции над группой объектов сущн. классов. Ну, в общем, хранение объектов и их обработка. Но тут вопрос: какие конкретно операции могут производиться над группой объектов?
8. Рефлексивные отношения (вот это под вопросом, я честно говоря, не понимаю зачем они вообще нужны).

Вроде всё, до чего додумался. Ещё вопрос: как происходит реализация наследования, если в РБД его нет. Я думаю, что если класс **Б** наследуется от **А**, то должна быть таблица, которая содержит поля и класса **А** и класса **Б**. В классе **А** нужно как-то ограничивать кол-во полей.

Цель этого поста: чтобы его прочитали и написали грамотный комментарий и ответы на вопросы.

Так же, ответьте на вопрос: что должна иметь ORM-библиотека, чтобы называться полноценной? Я всё перечислил или что-то упустил? И что нужно, чтобы библиотека была интересна не только мне?

Заранее спасибо :)

Comment: Видел ещё в интернете выражение "разные модели кеширования"... Оно нужно? Что это вообще?

Comment: @Лемур если вы уж зачем-то взялись за свой ORM, то хорошо бы ознакомиться с существующими. Тогда все ваши вопросы отпадут сами собой, и, скорее всего встанет другой, более важный вопрос: зачем? Как минимум ваш ORM должен чем-то отличаться от существующих, да так, чтобы это отличие кому-нибудь было нужно/важно.

Comment: @Лемур, имхо, лучше для ORM не изобретать собственный <s>велосипед</s> API, а имплементировать JPA (JSR-317 и прочие).

Comment: @Лемур: Ответьте себе для начала на вопрос: чем ваша ORM будет лучше чем, например, Hibernate[?](http://colinm.org/language_checklist.html)

Answer (score 2):

Я не великий специалист в разработке ORM, как говорится:

> чукча не писатель, чукча читатель

1. Уберите русскоязычные названия классов, я знаю, что `javac` и `IDE` умеют не ругаться на не ASCII идентификаторы, но что более важно, на это ругаются 99.9% девелоперов. Здесь дело не в неуважении к собственной стране, а в правилах. Почему то ведь вся медицина на латыни работает и ничего... Здесь то же самое.
2. Логгирование. Недавно здесь обсуждались системы логгирования и народ сошелся, что наиболее продвинутым будет использование библиотеки логгирования [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/) - позволяющей присоединять более-менее любую систему логгирования. Можно и старый добрый Log4J. Обычно в логи ORM выдают (в зависимости от уровня логгирования) - SQL запросы которые лежат в основе экзерсисов ORM.
3. Получение JDBC коннекта через JNDI имена/ресурсы (`javax.sql.DataSource`)
4. Кэширование JDBC коннектов, в частности реализация JDBC Pool
5. Кэширование SQL запросов (`PreparedStatement`/`CallableStatement`)
6. Кэширование результатов SQL запросов - `ResultSet`
7. Реализация разных моделей кэширования, например классический LRU (Least Recently Used) и проч. - [вагон и маленькая тележка](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_algorithms)

Ну и т.д.